# Showing relationships between Oracle views in a data model

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-visualization, data-modeling

I have set of Oracle data views which are created according to underlying table structures.

Now I want to represent these views visually with their relationships, just as the table relationships ( foreign keys ). Simply I want to create a model for data views indicating their relationship to other data views.

Is there any way to do this using Oracle SQL Developer? Or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

We can define primary keys and foreign keys on views.  These constraints must be DISABLED NOVALIDATE (that is, they are not enforced):

```
create or replace view v_dept 
    (deptno
     , dname
     , constraint vdept_pk primary key (deptno) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE
    ) as 
select deptno, dname 
from dept
/

create or replace view v_emp 
    (empno
     , ename
     , job
     , deptno
     , constraint vemp_pk primary key (empno) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE
     , constraint vemp_vdept_k foreign key (deptno) 
                    references v_dept(deptno) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE
    ) as 
select empno, ename, job, deptno 
from emp
/
```

These constraints help the optimizer and real people understand our physical data model.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#i1002565).

You don't say which version of SQL Dev Data Modeller you're using. Foreign key relationships on views are shown in version 4.1 or later.  [Find out more](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/01/modeling-view-dependencies-in-sql-developer-data-modeler/#view).

If you're using an earlier version of SQL Dev Data Modeller then you should upgrade :)   Alternatively, you'll have to fake the relationships, by rendering the views as say entities in the Logical Data Model or use a different drawing tool such as Powerpoint or Visio.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was used Oracle Sql Developer Data Modeler to take relationship between entity. It's freeware only.[image]

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Comment: is it possible with oracle sql developer data modeler ?  do I have to have foreign keys in data views , I looked in to this tool earlier but could not figured a way to do this , can you please tell me how it's been done with  developer data modeler ? , thanx in advance !

Comment: I didn't try in views. But it will definitely work on table relationship.

Comment: I just want to have relationships between view to other views , but in  data modeler I cant add relationships between views ,

Comment: @LakshithaUdara try microsoft visio , try the trial version of it http://download.cnet.com/s/microsoft-visio/